# JS: Reload the page without a specific param

Tags: javascript

I want to reload the page in Javascript without a specific param ie.

Let's say I want to reload www.domain.com/abc?num=4&something=1

But I want to reload www.domain.com/abc?number=4 only

Unfortunately the following keeps all of the params which isn't fit for my use case:

```
document.location.reload(false)
```

and:

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
```

gets rid of every parameter and just navigates to the path. Is there a way to delete a query param from window.location before navigating back to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location.href=location.href.replace(/&?somthing=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```

Comment: Slight syntax error there with the extra closing bracket at the end, but works great. Thanks! (I'm not able to edit less than 6 characters).